# How to resolve Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException

Tags: java, scala, solr, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to connect solr node using scala and query on existing table. How we can use query after resolving error solr query like as:

```
   select * from keyspace.table where solr_query = 'id: [1000 TO 2000]';
```

my code is here:

```
object SolrTest {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val url = "https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8983/solr"
    val httpClient: DefaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient()
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,  new   UsernamePasswordCredentials("XXXXX", "123456"))
    val server: HttpSolrServer = new HttpSolrServer(url, httpClient)
    val query = new SolrQuery()
    val myquery = query.setQuery("*:*")
    val response: QueryResponse = server.query(myquery)
    println("my response : "+ response)
  }
}
```

It is connecting successfully till connecting server. after getting following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8983/solr
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:437)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:180)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
at com.test.SolrTest$.main(SolrTest.scala:29)
at com.test.SolrTest.main(SolrTest.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

Comment: One of the common causes of this error is expired ssl certificates (on the https server in your instance). If that's not the case google for `SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated` as that's the root cause of the error.